# CTE to show all transitively related elements (siblings)

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table Siblings with Child ID columns Child1 and Child2:

| Child1 | Child2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 1 |

```
create table Siblings (Child1 int, Child2 int)
insert into Siblings values (1,2)
insert into Siblings values (2,3)
insert into Siblings values (4,6)
insert into Siblings values (5,1)
```

For each row, Child1 is a sibling of Child2 (and vice versa since sibling relationship is symmetric) e.g. 1 is sibling of 2 from the first row of the table above.  Also since 1 is a sibling of 2 and 2 is a sibling of 3, then 1 is also a sibling of 3 (sibling relationship is transitive).  Using TSQL how can I show all of the sibling relationships evident from the table above?  I am assuming use of recursive common table expressions (CTE) will be needed here. I've only started to dive into CTE's today so I am a bit stumped as to how to go about this.  I would like to see an output something like this:

| Child | Sibling |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 1 |

OR a select statement that will simply show all Child ID's that are siblings of a given Child ID.  Any help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: All the attempts I made to solve this myself I unfortunately did not save but were based on a very limited understanding of CTE's and a belief that a procedural construct involving recursion rather than a pure set-based approach would be needed.  I've seen a lot of vaguely similar pedigree/lineage type questions online but nothing involving a table where all you know is that for each row, column 1 is transitively related to column 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if there's a nice way to do this using CTEs. Here's something that works, and if nothing else, you can use it to test other solutions...

```
Drop Table If Exists #Siblings
Create Table #Siblings(Child1 Int, Child2 Int)
Insert Into #Siblings values (1,2),(2,3),(4,6),(5,1)

Drop Table If Exists #Res
Create Table #Res(C1 Int, C2 Int)

Insert Into #Res(C1, C2)
Select Child1, Child2 From #Siblings
Union
Select Child2, Child1 From #Siblings

Declare @RC Int = 1
While @RC > 0
Begin
  Insert Into #Res(C1, C2)
  Select R1.C1, R2.C2
  From
    #Res As R1
    Inner Join #Res As R2
      On R1.C2 = R2.C1
  Where Not Exists(Select *
                   From #Res As NoDupes
                   Where NoDupes.C1 = R1.C1 And NoDupes.C2 = R2.C2)
  Set @RC = @@ROWCOUNT
End
Select Distinct * From #Res Where C1 != C2 Order By 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks Stu.  This has handled every case I know to throw at it.